# How to fix bottom app bar to the bottom so that it do not come above the keyboard

Tags: java, android, xml, searchview, android-bottomappbar

[This is the screenshot of the screen which clearly shows the problem that I am facing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzP9w.jpg)

I am using Bottom app bar in my app. In a fragment I am using Recycler View and Search view but when I click the default search icon and the keyboard comes up.. Then the Bottom app does not disappears rather it comes above the keyboard as shown in the image..
The XML file of the layout file I am doing this is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment"
    android:id="@+id/home">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/searchbar"
        />


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/searchView"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

The java file in which I am using this is give below

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link HomeFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment HomeFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    }
}
```

The XML file of the bottom app bar is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NavigActivity">


    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">
        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp"
            app:menu="@menu/menu"
            app:buttonGravity="center_vertical"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
            />
        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"

            app:maxImageSize="35dp"/>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
 />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: XML of bottomappbar please

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin added sir

Comment: Use constraint layout instead of relative layout and set bottomtobottom to parent for bottomappbar

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin but what is someone wants to do it in Relative Layout

Comment: What is the advantage of relative layout for you? In constraint layout you can easily implement what you want.

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin actually I am also having a Frame Layout in it also which shows error when I use Constraint Layout and also I am used to Relative Layout that's why I prefer using it.Please tell me how to that in Relative Layout

Comment: Change  tools:context=".NavigActivity" from relativelayout to coordinator layout